# How to replace load jquery.js form local to link web CDN in require.js

Tags: jquery, magento-2.0.7, requirejs

When my page load require.js required jquery.js from local

> https://mypage/pub/static/frontend/../../en_US/jquery/jquery.min.js

And I want to change required from link web CDN

> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js